# Error running code inside Atom using 'Hydrogen'

Tags: python, tkinter, atom-editor, hydrogen

I'm fairly new to coding and was following a basic pong game tutorial using Python.
I've written the code in [Atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(text_editor)) and when I run it, the window closes instantly, so I am unable to see the GUI.

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title('Pong by Ijlal')
wn.bgcolor('black')
wn.setup(width=800, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)

# Paddle A
paddle_a = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_a.speed(0)
paddle_a.shape('square')
paddle_a.color('Red')
paddle_a.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
paddle_a.penup()
paddle_a.goto(-350, 0)

# Paddle B
paddle_b = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_b.speed(0)
paddle_b.shape('square')
paddle_b.color('blue')
paddle_b.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
paddle_b.penup()
paddle_b.goto(350, 0)
```

And when I try running it with [Hydrogen](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/hydrogen/info), I get an extensive error:

> Error Traceback:
> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Ijlal\anaconda3\envs\my_conda\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in *run_module_as_main return *run_code(code, main_globals, None, File "C:\Users\Ijlal\anaconda3\envs\my_conda\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in *run_code exec(code, run_globals) File "C:\Users\Ijlal\anaconda3\envs\my_conda\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in from ipykernel import kernelapp as app File "C:\Users\Ijlal\anaconda3\envs\my_conda\lib\site-packages\ipykernel__init**.py", line 2, in from .connect import File "C:\Users\Ijlal\anaconda3\envs\my_conda\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\connect.py", line 18, in import jupyter_client File "C:\Users\Ijlal\anaconda3\envs\my_conda\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client__init*_.py", line 4, in from .connect import File "C:\Users\Ijlal\anaconda3\envs\my_conda\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 21, in import zmq File "C:\Users\Ijlal\anaconda3\envs\my_conda\lib\site-packages\zmq__init__.py", line 50, in from zmq import backend File "C:\Users\Ijlal\anaconda3\envs\my_conda\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend__init__.py", line 40, in reraise(*exc_info) File "C:\Users\Ijlal\anaconda3\envs\my_conda\lib\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise raise value File "C:\Users\Ijlal\anaconda3\envs\my_conda\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend__init__.py", line 27, in *ns = select_backend(first) File "C:\Users\Ijlal\anaconda3\envs\my_conda\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend mod = import(name, fromlist=public_api) File "C:\Users\Ijlal\anaconda3\envs\my_conda\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython__init*_.py", line 6, in from . import (constants, error, message, context, ImportError: DLL load failed while importing error: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: You have to add `turtle.mainloop()`

Comment: Thankyou. That's resolved the problem. Now I have to figure out why it just displays a black screen with no graphics.

Answer (score 0):

Just add *wn.mainloop()*:

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title('Pong by Ijlal')
wn.bgcolor('black')
wn.setup(width=800, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)

# Paddle A
paddle_a = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_a.speed(0)
paddle_a.shape('square')
paddle_a.color('Red')
paddle_a.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
paddle_a.penup()
paddle_a.goto(-350, 0)

# Paddle B
paddle_b = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_b.speed(0)
paddle_b.shape('square')
paddle_b.color('blue')
paddle_b.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
paddle_b.penup()
paddle_b.goto(350, 0)

wn.mainloop()
```